# How to manually clear DB in a Django test?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework, django-testing, django-tests

I am using:
python = "3.8.3",
django="3.0.5"

I have written a django test with [APITestCase](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing/#api-test-cases). I am running other tests inside my test class. I am trying to call other functions inside my test class. In order to do this I have a dictionary in a list which i mapped like this:

```
[
   {
      "class_name": class_name,
      "func_name": "test_add_product", # Comes test name
      "trigger_type": trigger_type, # Comes from model choices field.
      "request_type": RequestTypes.POST,
      "success": True,
   },
   {
       ...
   },

]
```

I am looping these with a for loop and running each one. After each loop db should be cleared in order to not get error. I tried to do this using:

```
# Lets say that, we have a Foo model
Foo.objects.all().delete()
```

This method works, but I want a better solution.

**How can I manually clear the test db before the test finishes?**

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
from django.test import Client, TestCase

class TestsDB(TestCase):
    def __init__(self):
       self.e = Client()
    def test_delete_db(self):
        foo = Foo.objects.all()
        foo.delete()
```